Delete records based intervals date in text format
In mysql table we have one column intervals type text
select intervals from scheduled_jobs_v2 where job_id='agg-c902817b-90fc-4396-a61b-57f0b1169d21-PM-5G-huawei_dc-1hour-cell-11233806883185660' limit 1  \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
intervals: 1715986800,1716879600,1715900400,1715904000,1716876000,1716879600

select from_unixtime(intervals); output is  2024-05-17 23:00:00  it is converting value for 1st interval where as all interval values are as below
select from_unixtime(1715986800);
2024-05-17 23:00:00 
select from_unixtime(1716879600);
2024-05-28 07:00:00
 
select from_unixtime(1715900400);
2024-05-16 23:00:00
select from_unixtime(1715904000);
2024-05-17 00:00:00
 
select from_unixtime(1716876000);
2024-05-28 06:00:00
 
select from_unixtime(1716879600);
2024-05-28 07:00:00

Can you provide the query where we can delete all the records of table scheduled_jobs_v2 which contains interval less than last 2 days interval .

Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?

See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, provide sample data and desired output for them according to #5 and #3.

You can use JSON_TABLE() to turn the comma separated list into rows.
DELETE scheduled_jobs_v2
FROM scheduled_jobs_v2
JOIN JSON_TABLE(
  CONCAT('[', intervals, ']'),
  '$[*]' COLUMNS (ts INT PATH '$')
) AS i
WHERE i.ts <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 DAY);

Here's a db<>fiddle.
